# My projects symbols are not loaded for debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, castle-windsor, .net-assembly

I have multiple projects and one will not allow me to debug any of the code due to the symbols not being loaded.

What makes this project different to the others is that none of its classes are called directly (they are all loaded using Windsor).

I have other projects that also have classes loaded using Windsor, however they also have some classes which I instantiate manually. I decided to mimic this behavior and create a dummy class and instantiate it. Bingo! the symbols were loaded.

I don't, however, wish to keep a dummy class and instantiate it just to allow debugging.

I have also tried (in an attempt to force them loaded) specifying the source files in **Debug Source Files** under **options** for the solution, and specifying the symbol location in **Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols**, but neither of these options worked (or possibly didn't configure them correctly).

Is there a way I can force the symbols for this project to be loaded, either through Visual Studio or perhaps Windsor has the capabilities?

Windsor code in case it's necessary. Where AssemblyB is the one I can't get symbols to load for.

```
IWindsorContainer _container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.Named("AssemblyA")).Install(FromAssembly.Named("AssemblyB"));
```

And the classes are installed like this.

```
public class MapperInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
  public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
  {
    container.Register(
      Classes.FromThisAssembly()
        .BasedOn(typeof(IDataMapper<>))
        .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
        .LifestyleTransient()
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Windsor does, but what kind of projects do you have?
You can have multiple debugging sessions. Just right click the project that "doesn't load symbols", go to Debug and click start new instance. This is valid for projects that can be ran. 
For class library's you just need a reference to them, to be able to debug them

Comment: I managed to make this work by referencing the project in my startup project. I had **startup project** reference **projectA** which referenced **projectB and projectC** with project C being the one the symbols weren't loaded for. This setup looks fine to me, but for whatever reason wasn't working. By referencing projectC in the startup project (even though it has no need for it) the symbols are now loading.